# Round div height up to certain amounts

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to keep various elements in a grid layout using Isotope and they need to expand to different sizes depending on the amount of content inside them, always incrementing up by a certain amount - a grid unit height is 77px with 7px gutters. The expanded width will always stay the same so isn't important here.

The min-height for an expanded element would be 329px, but if the calculated height goes to 330px or more then the min-height would need to be 413px (77px + 7px gutter). Then if the calculated height was > 414px then it would jump to the next threshold of 497px etc etc.

Any help setting this height value using JS? (mostly this is already done with jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [`height`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) will tell you the natural height of the element. Then you just use a series of `if...else` statements (or a calculation) to set the height to a specific value via [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/). So on resize, you'll want to remove the forced height, measure, and then apply a (new) forced height.

Comment: Yep, this is how I'm doing it at the moment it just feels a bit clumsy having to hard code in all the permutations and I assume there's some neat little algorithm that would do it inifinitely. but it's not the end of the world as I know roughly what the largest it can get will be, I was just looking for a bit of learning for the future!!